# NameError: global name 'add_to_receives' is not defined | add_to_receives(msg_to)

Tags: python, django

```
def add_to_receivers(receivers):    # make sure they are unique
    for receiver in receivers:
        name, email = receiver
        if email not in [u'', None]:    # empty receiver pairs are possible
        #print email            
            if email not in msg_receivers and email is not None:
                msg_receivers.append(email.lower())


msg_receivers = [] 
add_to_receives(msg_to) 
add_to_receives(msg_cc)
add_to_receives(msg_bcc) # in essence, we don’t care how the message was received 
#add_to_receives(msg_delivered_to)
```

please help me with fixing this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metadata.py", line 309, in worker
    add_to_receives(msg_to)
NameError: global name 'add_to_receives' is not defined
```

full code you can see at http://brage.bibsys.no/xmlui/handle/11250/198551

Comment: You ere simply missing an `r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the function is called `add_to_receivers`and you are calling `add_to_receives` (without the 'r')

Comment: thank you, yes it was stupid typo which i not realized, after exectution script gaved me this output and do not have a clue how to fix it:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metadata.py", line 516, in <module>
    main()
  File "metadata.py", line 491, in main
    address_book[result["current_user_email"]] = result["username"]
KeyError: 'current_user_email'